# How do you vertically align a button in a nav that is using line-height?

Tags: html, css

How can I vertically align a button in a nav that is using `line-height` while keeping my specified padding dimensions?

I'd like to align this button with the rest of the nav elements:

[image: padding]

I'm using `line-height` to align the others, but using `line-height` on the button creates unwanted results:

[image: line]

**Summary:** I'm vertically aligning my nav list items with `line-height` but this makes my button extend the full height of the nav bar. I need to use line height to vertically align this ul with another ul that contains the site icon. The `line-height` height used is the icon's height.

Please see the issue recreated here
<kbd>[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L9B7T/1/)</kbd>.

html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Text</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Text</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Text</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="button">Text</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    border: 1px solid;
    float: right;
    width: auto;
    height: auto !important;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}
ul li {
    line-height: 103px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    direction: ltr;
}
ul li a {
    line-height: 103px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0 15px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.button {
    padding: 0.5em;
    background: grey;
}
```

Comment: @Burdock Exactly; as you can see from the fiddle, the button's horizontal padding takes up the height of the element, when I've specified it to take up only 0.5em's of the nav (30px or so). I'm trying to make it only take up that 0.5em so it looks like a normal button.

Comment: See my answer's linked jsfiddle :: I think it should solve your problem.

Comment: Remove `padding: 0.5em;` from the `.button`

Comment: @mdesdev I'd like to have the button horizontally aligned, not stretched out to the full hight of the ul. Removing the padding only aligns the stretched out method. Checkout my updated question, I think I made it more clear.

Comment: Maybe you could try to use real button instead of anchor and apply this css `.button { height: 22px; top: 50%; margin-top: -11px; padding: 0.5em; background: grey; border: none; outline: none;
}`

Answer (score 1):

The easy fix is to apply the class to the  column (IE: `<li class="button">`)  instead of the link: `<a href="#" class="button">` (See [edit here](http://jsfiddle.net/L9B7T/2/))

If you can't do this, you will have to play around with, height, and width styles, or create a div to make your link fit

Edit: By changing the style to `padding:0 0.5em;` you will not get the vertical displacement

Comment: I'm not trying to use padding for verical alignment, please check out my updated question, I think it might better explain things.

Answer (score 0):

You can `vertically-align` by doing

CSS:

```
div {
    height: 300px;
}
a {
    line-height: 300px;
}
```

Put the `a` in the `div` and you should be all set.

Comment: I'm already aligning the elements that way, the issue is to keep the vertical alignment, while maintaing my desired padding.

Answer (score 0):

> Add `display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle` instead of `float:left` in `li` tag